# Bootstrap4 - navbar-collapse won't vertically centre-align

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap v4, I noticed that when a logo increases the height of the navbar the navbar-collapse menu is centre-aligned vertically, I guess because of the display: flex.

How can I make the navbar-collapse menu align at the top of the navbar - this demo illustrates the issue:

```
<div id="app" class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

I've tried removing the display: flex and changing it to inline but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Add **align-items-start** class to **navbar** and it will align navbars' content to top.

```css
.navbar-brand {
  height: 60px;
}

/* use "align-items-start" class, or */
.navbar {
  align-items: flex-start !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div id="app" class="container">
  <!-- add "align-items-start" to navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light align-items-start">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```